# Wrapper in Laravel API output

Tags: api, laravel-5.6

I have an API output like below

```
"id": 1,
"employee_id": 1,
"text": "good",
"employee": "Jamal"
```

My query is like below

```
return $company
            ->employee()
            ->with('motorcycle', 'children')
            ->join('shop', function ($join) {
                $join->on('shop.shop_id', '=', 'attendence.shop_id');
                $join->on('shop.employee_id', '=', 'residence.employee_id');
            })
            ->get();
```

I would like to get output like below

```
"company": {
     "id": 1,
     "employee_id": 1,
     "text": "good",
     "employee": "Jamal"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my api.php
It will first validate you data then give output as you mentioned.

```
Route::get('articles', function() {

    $articles = article::all();
        if(count($articles) == 0){
           $feedback = [
              'status'     => "error",
              'message'    => "data not found",
              'company'    => null
           ]; 

        }else{
            $articles = [
               'status'     => "success",
               'message'    => "data found",
               'company'    => $articles
            ]; 
        }

    return $articles;
});
```